# Return more than one result in modal angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

I have an angularjs app.
I added a button to my app and when a user clicks on it , a pop up screen is displayed.
The user should choose from 2 drop down lists so i have two values that i need to send back to my service who opened the modal screen.

The service that opens the pop up screen

```
app.service('OriginalService', [ '$modal',
function ($modal) {

this.openDialog = function(){
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'ModalScreen.html',
            controller: 'ModalController'
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (oneFilter, secondFilter) {
            this.filtersMananger.oneFilter= oneFilter;
            this.filtersMananger.secondFilter= secondFilter;
        }, function () {

        });
    };
}]);
```

In the ModalController when i click OK i sent the two values:

```
app.controller('ModalController', ['$scope', '$modalInstance',
                                     function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

$scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.filterMananger.oneFilter, 
                             $scope.filterMananger.secondFilter);
    };
}]);
```

The problem is that only the first value is return to the service.
I saw in other examples and maybe in angular they expected to one result only:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (result)
```

Can i send two or values as a result or must i send an object with the two values only in this case?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you take a look at `$modal` [source code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js) you will see this lines:

```
var modalInstance = {
    result: modalResultDeferred.promise,
    opened: modalOpenedDeferred.promise,
    close: function(result) {
        $modalStack.close(modalInstance, result);
    },
    dismiss: function(reason) {
        $modalStack.dismiss(modalInstance, reason);
    }
};
```

From which it's clear, that `close` and `dismiss` methods accept only one `result` parameter. So you have to pass and object or array if you want to pass several.

Answer (score 2):

> Can i send two or values as a result

Unless you implement some other way for the modal to communicate with the calling code (which I suspect would be needlessly complicated), you can only send one value.

This is because the value passed to `close` ends up being the resolved value of the `modalInstance.result` promise. Promises only have one resolved value. But as you have noted, you can send an object, so this single value can be a wrapper for multiple.